# In SSRS, tablix not picking up the text generated in a dynamic SQL for grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

In SSRS, I have written a dynamic sql in which a column is populated from a case statement. The sql query is correctly populating the column in sql result but when I use it in a tablix for creating a group and summing it by 'X' column as shown below. It does not populate at all. Rest of tablix is populating fine. Can somebody please help.

eg: The columns generated by SQL has below result. Bucket is generated by case statement. In tablix I want the first row to be grouped by Bucket and in next row sum by the x column

```
>  **X**   **Bucket**
>     0     NULL
>     1     Today
>     1     1-10
>     1     11-20
>     0     NULL
>     1     1-10
>     1     Today
>     1     20-30
```

Expected Result

```
> Today  1-10  11-20  20-30
>   2     2      1      1
```

Comment: @Alan Schofield Hey Alan, please see you could help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your layout?

Answer (score 0):

Set your **column** grouping expression to Bucket and the detail row will simply have an expression like `=SUM(Fields!X.Value)`.

You don't need any **row** grouping

Comment: I am already doing that. I think the issue is of formatting. When I used the SQL code directly by hard coding it and not using the dynamic sql. The buckets came fine. When using the dynamic sql bucket column does not show up at all

Comment: Finally found the issue after 4 hours. My buckets in case statement are calculated using dates and in dynamic sql when I changed the format of the date using convert. The buckets started coming fine. It was not required in the direct SQL. Dynamic sql has its own shenanigans :)